# PHP: Renaming Namespace leads to 'Class not found'

Tags: php, wordpress

Following a class-based Wordpress theming tutorial I wanted to build a boilerplate theme where I could rename all namespaces, prefixes etc. with search and replace.

after changing everything I got the following error:

```
Class 'THE_WORDPRESS_THEME_BOILERPLATE_THEME\inc\THE_WORDPRESS_THEME_BOILERPLATE_THEME' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/boilerplate/wp-content/themes/The_Wordpress_Theme_Boilerplate/functions.php:60
```

As a reference, when I used SALEMOCHE_THEME it worked. When I used the tutorial Theme and would change it to e.g. SALEMO_THEME, it would not work.

I'm using a singleton trait and an autoloader.

I guess I'm not fully understanding the concept of namespaces since in my opinion, when I update the namespace name in all locations, there is no way it could not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you do a `composer dump-autoload` after changing the namespace?

Comment: I used a different method for autoloading but I did some reading on the composer autoloading and have made it work. i used [this resource](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-autoload-classes-with-composer-in-php--cms-35649) for whoever is interested